# Adjusting directory structure in Visual Studio messing up #includes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ide, directory

I'm sure there is a simple way to fix this somewhere in Visual Studio's settings, but I can't figure it out at all. Here's my issue: I'm a novice programmer who's trying to work on my first large multimedia project, and I've realized that it would be in my best interest to set up a project file directory structure that is more organized to suit my needs. Up until today I've been just using Visual Studio's default directory and build options. As of now, my project is only about 10 headers and 10 source files, so I thought it would be a good choice to re-arrange everything sooner rather than later. I thought that the easiest way to do this would be to start a clean 'solution' and just import my old files.

Here's my *planned folder structure:*

```
-Solution
    -Project
        -Source Files
        -Header Files
        -Multimedia Assets
        -Release Builds
        -Documentation
```

Now, as I'm new to Visual C++, I didn't realize that creating all these folders inside the 'solution explorer' does not create actual folders inside windows. (So it seems to me at least..)

So, I went ahead and created a mirrored set of REAL folders inside my Solution\Project\ directory. I placed all my headers within my Header Files folder, all my source code inside my Source Files folder, etc.

The problem I have now, is that Visual C++ is clearly expecting all my files to be within the same directory. And my existing #includes no longer work. I've tried changing them to be -

```
#include "Headers\xxxxx.h"
```

- But, that doesn't seem to work either. I'm not sure *where I have to go to inform Visual Studio C++ Express where the root directory is*. Once I figure that out, I would guess that it would be as simple as including the file path from that root directory.

**Is there a way to set the 'root directory' for my project to be my 'Project' folder? Or is there a better way to manage my file directory when using Visual Studio C++ Express?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is set on a per-project basis. In the properties of the project, go to `C/C++` > `General` > `Additional Include Directories` and add the required directory(ies) there. You might want to use macros like `$(ProjectDir)` or `$(SolutionDir)` to make it more abstract - or not, as your particular case may be.

**EDIT**

If you have many projects which need the same settings, you might also consider creting a property file for such settings and adding this file to all the projects, so that it if a change is necessary later, it can be done in one place.

To do that, open Property Manager, right-click a project and select `Add New Project Property Sheet...` or `Add Existing Property Sheet...` as applicable.

Note: I've never used VS Express, so I don't know whether it supports propety sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Open the property page of the project, go to C/C++ tab, then "General" and the add these directories t o additional include directories.

To figure out how VC compiler search these include directories, go to "Advanced" in the project property page, enable "Show Inlcudes".